# Not getting ConfigMapKeyRef for env entry in AdmissionController

Tags: kubernetes, webhooks

I'm working on a `MutatingAdmissionWebhook` monitoring `Deployment` objects in Go. The webhook is running and receives the request correctly.

I am trying to read through the Deployment->Spec->Container->env List.

I am able to get the env list, but I have `ConfigMapKeyRef` defined for these env vars, which is coming in as nil.

When I dumped the `ValueFrom` here is what I got

```
%!(EXTRA *v1.EnvVarSource=&EnvVarSource{FieldRef:nil,ResourceFieldRef:nil,
ConfigMapKeyRef:nil,SecretKeyRef:&SecretKeySelector{
LocalObjectReference:LocalObjectReference{Name:myuser,},Key:username,Optional:nil,},})
```

I am expecting to find a full name of the `ConfigMap` in the `ConfigMapKeyRef`.

I'm running Kubernetes Client v1.14.0

Any help to solve this?

Thanks,

-Sreeni

Comment: Can you post the whole deployment and your code please?

Answer (score 0):

It means that object reference is not set to an instance of an object.

Here is similar problem: [NilReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it).

**Tips to Prevent Nil Reference Exceptions**

1. Initialize variables with valid values.
2. If a variable can be null, then check for nill and handle it appropriately
3. Use the ? operator on methods when possible. stringvar?.ToUpper();
4. Use tools like Resharper to help point out potential nill reference exceptions

Useful article: [admission-webhooks](https://banzaicloud.com/blog/k8s-admission-webhooks/).

Admission Controller documentation: [admission-controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/).

Answer (score 0):

**Tested with**:
 
 - validating admission Webhook (node-js)
 - Kubernetes v1.15.2
 - Pod spec:

```
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: nginx-with-env
    env:
    - name: PASSWORD
      value: fail
    - name: PASSWORD
      value: fail
    - name: SPECIAL_LEVEL_KEY
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: special-config
          key: SPECIAL_LEVEL
    - name: SPECIAL_TYPE_KEY
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: special-config
          key: SPECIAL_TYPE
```

I don't have any issue with reading this value ("full name of the ConfigMap in the ConfigMapKeyRef") out of AdmissionReview request object.

when I dump the value of one of such envs using ConfigMap's data, e.g: `container.env[2].valueFrom`, I'm getting JSON like object:

`{"configMapKeyRef":{"name":"special-config","key":"SPECIAL_LEVEL"}`}.

In Go lang you should refer to data in context with following syntax:

```
env.ValueFrom.ConfigMapKeyRef.Name
```